# TypeError when calling an object's attribute in a little card game

Tags: python, string

I'm writing a card game.

I have made a 'card' class, and a deck class with card objects in it as an attribute. I successfully made up functions to shuffle, to print the deck cards list, to print the remaining card in the deck and to make a functioning "draw" system. 
Now I'm trying to give to every Card an attribute ("Briscola" = True/False) based on the card's seed (A first card is drawn by the dealer, its seed is considered then the value of Briscola is changed to True for every card matching that exctracted seed) but i encountered 2 problems.

When I try to run

```
prova = Mazzo()
prova.inizio()
```

the "inizo" method (which should pick a card and do the seed stuff) gives out this TypeError:

```
in inizio
    print('La briscola è', self.semi[brisc.Seme])
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here is what i wrote:

```
import random

class Carta:
    semi = ['Bastoni', 'Spade', 'Coppe', 'Denari']
    numeri = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 'Fante', 'Cavallo', 'Re']
    briscola = None
    def __init__(self, Seme = 0, Valore = 0, Briscola = False):
        self.Seme = Seme
        self.Valore = Valore
        self.Briscola = Briscola
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.numeri[self.Valore] + " di " +
                self.semi[self.Seme])
class Mazzo:
    semi = ['Bastoni', 'Spade', 'Coppe', 'Denari']
    numeri = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 'Fante', 'Cavallo', 'Re']

    def __init__(self):
        self.Carte = []
        for seme in range(4):
            for valore in range(10):
                self.Carte.append(Carta(seme,valore))
    def inizio(self):
        brisc = random.choice(self.Carte)
        print = ('-------------La partita è iniziata!-------------')
        print('La carta iniziale è ' , brisc)
        print('La briscola è', self.semi[brisc.Seme])
        for carta in self.Carte:
            if carta.Seme == brisc.Seme:
                carta.Briscola = True
        self.Carte.remove(brisc)
```

I'm sorry but variable names are in my native language. Here is some translation for better understanding:
carta/e = card/s   seme/i = seed/s    Mazzo = deck    numeri = numbers   prova = foo

Comment: You assigned a string to print, shadowing the built-in function.

Comment: You have a typo: `print = ('-------------La partita è iniziata!-------------')` should be `print('-------------La partita è iniziata!-------------')` without the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print = ('-------------La partita è iniziata!-------------')
```

That line reassigns the `print()` function to be a plain string, and it's not a function anymore.

So the next time you call `print('something')`, you get an error.

Presumably that's a typo, and you didn't mean to have the `=` in there.